# is there anyway to keep my WatchKit app running in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, core-motion

I'm a newbie on swift and WatchKit framework.I'm studying this from only a month.Now my question is:is possible running an app in background mode on the apple watch?I read from the documentation that the WatchKit extensions do not support background execution modes.But if this thing is true how to work apps like health app?I mean,on the watch there is an app called health that takes at each instant of time your hearth rate even if the app is not in foreground.I would do the same thing more or less.In my app I would detect the user acceleration only when the user move the watch even if the app is not in foreground.How can I do? Please to post me the necessary documentation to do so.Thanks a lot!

Ps. sorry for my english!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are several ways:

1. Start a workout using [HKWorkoutSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkworkoutsession) - the most powerful way, however you need to use HealthKit and only 1 app on the Apple Watch can run this way.
2. Play audio in the background using [WKAudioFilePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkaudiofileplayer) - only for audio.
3. [WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkurlsessionrefreshbackgroundtask) suitable for short background refreshes.
4. There are other background tasks, such as `WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask` or `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask`. They are listed in Background Tasks section of [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInwatchOS/Articles/watchOS3.html).
5. [`performExpiringActivity(withReason:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1617030-performexpiringactivitywithreaso) can be used to shortly prolong life of the app when it goes to the background.

Also, read [Leveraging iOS Technologies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html).

Answer (score 3):

With WatchOS 6+ your watch app can request a [`WKExtendedRuntimeSession` (see documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession?language=objc) if it falls into one of the following 5 use cases:

- self care
- mindfulness
- physical therapy
- alarms
- health monitoring

Relevant WWDC video explaining the `WKExtendedRuntimeSession`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/251/

Comment: What if my app doesn't fall into these categories? If so, what happens if I still choose one as my background mode?

Comment: If you choose an inadequate category for your app, just to be able to run your app in background mode, I guess the most likely thing is that your app will be rejected in the review process for the app store. There's a reason why Apple pulled in these categories in the first place, they don't want any app developer to misuse them.

Answer (score 1):

In watchOS 3 workout apps can run in the background. I don't have personal experience, but check WWDC 2016 video [Building Great Workout Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/235/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing same issue. I want to execute some code when the app is in background mode. I have resolved this issue. I have discovered an additional state in which my watch app will continue to run in the Background which does not require `HKWorkoutSession` or any other solution's discussed above. Just follow these steps

1. import `CoreLocation`
2. Add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the class
3. Add the following code in `willActive` method.

   ```
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
   if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 3.0, *) {
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   } else {
       // Fallback on earlier versions
   }

   if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *) {
       locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
   } else {
      print("Location not updated")
   }
   ```
4. And in the last just add the CLLocationManagerDelegate

> ```
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
>     print("Location updated\(locations)")
> }
>
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
>     print("Location_update_error\(error)")
> }
> ```

May be this will resolve your problem.